# Passar valores dentro de <frameset>

Tags: javascript, html

---

Tenho duas páginas, onde esta recebe dados, escrevendo o nome do produto e descrição:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Código:
    <input name="campo1" id="campo1" type="text">

    Descrição: 
    <label name="descrproduto" id="descrproduto">
    </label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

E esta, que vai enviar dados para a anterior:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script> function levarcodigo( codigo,descricao )

       {top.opener.document.getElementById("campo1").value = codigo;
        top.opener.document.getElementById("descrproduto").innerHTML = descricao;}
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="grey">
    <a href="javascript:levarcodigo(1010,'Cafeteira');">1010-Cafeteira</a>
    <a href="javascript:levarcodigo(1020,'Jogo de panelas');">1020-Jogo de panelas</a>
    <a href="javascript:levarcodigo(1030,'Jogo de taças');">1030-Jogo de taças</a>
    <a href="javascript:levarcodigo(1040,'Churrasqueira');">1040-Churrasqueira</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Elas funcionam em páginas separadas mas como eu faço elas funcionarem dentro de frames?

Comment: As duas páginas dentro de frames? Então no caso, seriam 3 páginas?

Comment: Sim, no total será três

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode selecionar o frame que vai receber o valor pelo `id`. Basta colocar os dois `iframe`s com esta estrutura básica:

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="p1.php"></iframe>
<iframe src="p2.php"></iframe>
```

Onde `p1.php` possui o campo e a `div` que receberão os valores. `p2.php` é onde estão os links.

Na `p2.php`, você irá usar este script:

```
<script>
function levarcodigo( codigo,descricao ){
   // seleciona o iframe com o id "#frame1" na página-mãe
   var iFrame1 = top.document.body.querySelector("#frame1");
   iFrame1.contentDocument.getElementById("campo1").value = codigo;
   iFrame1.contentDocument.getElementById("descrproduto").innerHTML = descricao;
}
</script>
```

`p1.php` e `p2.php` são apenas exemplos de nomes das páginas. Altera para as que você quer usar.